# String gets escaped, how to safely print

Tags: java, groovy

The issue I am having is that the following string escapes and errors out like:

```
Dont' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'display' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'Recipes' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'if' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'active' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'subscription' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'is' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'missing' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Code:

```
  gitlogFirst = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log -n1 --pretty=\'format:%s\'').trim()
  gitlogRest = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log --pretty=\'format:%s\' ${GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT:-HEAD^}..HEAD^').trim()
  gitMsg = "${cimsg}\n\n${gitlogFirst}\n${gitlogRest}"
  authorName = 'Jenkins CI'
  authorEmail = 'ci@jenkins'
  author = "${authorName} <${authorEmail}>"
  dir (path) {
    sh "git add . && GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='${authorName}' GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='${authorEmail}' git commit --author='${author}' -m '${gitMsg}' || :"
    withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: '***', variable: 'GIT_CRED')]) {
      sh "git push https://${GIT_CRED}@github.com/xxx/xxxx.git ${branch}"
    }
  }
```

How do you escape characters in java/groovy for a variable safely?

Comment: what and why do you want to escape?

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear, I dont want it to escape.

Comment: It less clear now.

Comment: I guess it's because of git commit multiline message in -m parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make

> git fetch

your local repository get all the new information from github. It just takes information about new branches and no real code. After that,

> git checkout

should work fine.